# How to trace color value as hex number?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, colors, hex

Actionscript: how to output color value in format like "#FF00FF00"

So I use such code to generate colors ond simply trace tham. How to trace tham in Hex format?

```
            var xn:Number;
            var yn:Number;
            var zn:Number;
            var norm:Number;
            var c1:Number;
            var c2:Number;
            var c3:Number;
            var c4:Number;
            var counter:int;
            while (counter < 12000)
            {
                xn = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
                yn = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
                zn = Math.random() * 400 - 200;
                norm = Math.sqrt(xn * xn + yn * yn + zn * zn);
                c1 = (1 - norm / 200) * 255;
                c2 = (1 - norm / 250) * 255;
                c3 = Math.abs(xn) / norm * 255;
                c4 = Math.abs(yn) / norm * 255;
                trace(String(c1 << 24 | c2 << 16 | c3 << 8 | c4));
                counter++;
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *toString* method:

```
rgb = 255;
hex = rgb.toString(16);
```

**Edit**: As dome said this method just gives you the hexadecimal representation of a value. You should not convert the color value like this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [post](http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/36-uint-to-6-digit-rgb-hex-actionscript-30-as3).

The method aeby describes color.toString(16) its not a accurate method to get your color converted.
[EDIT] better link for some reading about proper [color convertion](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/rgbs/index.html) and alpha [extraction](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/rgbs/explanations.html)

Comment: we here use rgba - not rgb=) having values like ' 708c5a22,
234fcb89, 12dce656,
ffffffff '

Comment: Sorry to say this, but the post you've linked to is kind of lame. It mixes hexadecimal and octal as if they where the same to begin with. It uses a bunch of methods and objects to solve a very simple and specific formatting problem. The only thing that uint.toString(16) is missing is zero padding, which is not that hard anyway; you can use some padding function or you can even do the padding with a one-liner, like this for example (the second line): `var str:String = (255).toString(16); var hex:String = ("#000000").substr(0,7 - str.length) + str;`. Or maybe I'm missing something?